# Coordinator Layout Error in android app development

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, kotlin

I'm pretty new in Android app development.
I started with Kotlin and after configuring SDK I started a project but I don't have any idea what the problem is. 
I expected to see `Base theme` that has "Hello World!" `TextView`.

[image]

[image: XML code]

How can I solve this problem/Error?

### App Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dell.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: can you show the xml code?

Comment: Sure!  image added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Support Library v`28.0.0-rc02` has this issue-bug which it has been discussed for too many times in here. Anyways,

To fix this, you'll need to use older Support libaries like `27.1.1` or this bypass which should be added in `/app > Build.gradle` :

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion "27.+"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Or, you can download the **Canary version** of Android Studio in canary channel to fix this issue.

Comment: Just to be clear enough: **`rc02`** is the **Release Candidate** and it means it's still in development. That's what RC means:.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `rc` stuff for these:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

And then `Build > Clean code / Rebuild project`

Answer (score -2):

You can try to rebuild your project from Build > Rebuild project option